# Converting an integer to an object and back causes InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, object, .net

I'm trying to store 3 variables in a ListViewItem's Tag object. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
lvi.Tag = new object[] { value1, value2, value3 };
```

This is not a problem, but when I try to revert it with this code:

```
object[] objs = (lvi.Tag as object[]);
int t = (int)objs[0];
```

It gives me an exception `System.InvalidCastException`. I've tried debugging it, but the debugger gives me the correct information

```
objs = object[] { 1, 93234, 0 }
```

Does anyone have an idea what is happening?

Comment: why are you using an `object` array?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't see why not? If I want to store different data (such as a string) I cannot include that in a different array, as far as I know.

Comment: Use a class then. Its bad practice to use an array to store data based on position.

Comment: Try doing `objs[0].GetType().ToString()` -- what does it tell you? If it tells you anything other than "int", then that explains it; you can only unbox a boxed int to int.

Comment: if you split it into `object foo = objs[0]; int t = (int)foo;` does that tell you any more (eg by inspection of foo before the cast, etc.)? I tested this with just putting the array into a new object array rather than a property of an object and it worked fine...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works perfectly fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Tag = new object[] { 1, 93234, 0 };

        object[] objs = (lvi.Tag as object[]);
        int t = (int)objs[0];
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

So I guess you have doubles (or decimals or floats), but not integers, so make sure that you are casting back to the correct type:

```
double t = (double)objs[0];
```

Comment: The problem was indeed caused by a wrong convert. The objects were not integers (I think unsigned longs or something?) and were parsed like integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would store your tags as instance of a class. That way it can remain strongly typed as soon as you cast it out.

```
class TagModel {
   int[] MyInts { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        lvi.Tag = new TagModel() { MyInts = new int[] { 1, 93234, 0 }};

        var tagModel = (lvi.Tag as TagModel);
        int t = tagModel.MyInts[0];
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```